# Error on rewrite rule inside subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When my website was inside the root directory of my hosting, everything works find. However, I had to move my website files to a subdirectory.

Old:

```
/www/*
```

Current:

```
/www/websites/example
```

Now, I can visit the homepage of my website, but I get error when I visit other pages of my site.

```
example.com/1234/title_of_url -> example.com/index.php?qa-rewrite=1234/title_of_url
```

But when I visit that sample page, i get the following error.

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Note: I have moved the file to my `/www/` dir and it works fine. So I think I am missing to put `websites/example` somewhere in my `.htaccess`

Comment: @anubhava I am using GoDaddy shared hosting, so I no, I do not have control.

Comment: @anubhava Yes it is working fine. just test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/websites/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* websites/example/$0 [L]
```

Then use this code in `websites/example/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /websites/example/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php$).*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: But I have other websites next to `websites/example`, `websites/example222`, `websites/example3333`

Comment: It is not working, I got `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: You will need to check your Apache error.log for this as both of these .htaccess are working fine on my Apache.